# Private GitHub repository for reading anonymous user?

Tags: java, linux, git, github, repository

I am trying to share a private GitHub repository of a Java app with people who has not a GitHub account. When I add collabrator via email, it sends link to that mail but requires GitHub account to read shared repo.

So, is it possible to share repo with a person who has not GitHub account?

Comment: Git is designed around *clones*, so you don't literally share the repository. They do, however, have to be able to get their own clone of (i.e., copy all the commits from) the GitHub repository, in some way. Any way suffices: for instance, you can convert the entire repository into a bundle, and then email a text-encoding of the bundle file. They can then share individual commits with you by any method that lets them send the commits, e.g., `git format-patch` and email.

Comment: @torek Thanks a lot for your good explanations. Actually I just want to share my code with some people so that they can check, but they do not need to make a review, make comment, etc. So, the way I tried seems ok, but not sure if there is a more proper way for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they do not need the full history, but only the latest code, sending an archive (`git archive` or [GitHub tarball](https://blog.abelotech.com/posts/how-download-github-tarball-using-curl-wget/)) is enough.

That is the equivalent of a `git bundle` limited to one commit.

If they need to look at the history, and the bundle is not an option, then they need a GitHub account, as anonymous browsing is not available for a *private* repository.

Comment: Thanks a lot, voted up. But it would probably needed to have a look at the history. Then, I think the best way is to create a collaborate link and share with them. The weird thing is they need to have GitHub account even for reading.